# How to freeze this version and next updated code add to other place in GIT?

Tags: git, version-control

I finished version 1.0 of the project.

How to freeze this version and next updated(version2) code add to other place in GIT? (this should be new branch?)

Can I ask for detailed instructions what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Using the commitish (SHA1 hash) of the commits in question, you can tag them

```
git tag version-1.0 <first commit in question>
git tag version-2.0 <second commit in question>
```

Comment: Note that you should run the `git tag` command on the last commit that contains the code which you released as version 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

search your log and find  that you want to tag

```sh
git tag -a <tag_name> -m 'summary for version <tag_name>' <hash_of_commit>
```

`git tag -a` creates annotated tag where `-m` provides comment for that tag - you could work as you were doing till this time - nothing changes before or after creation of tag

if for some reason you would like to keep archived pack of that tag you could use command below

```
git archive --format=tar --prefix=<path_to_folder>/ <tag_name> |
  gzip > pack-<tag_name>.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tag the GIT repository to forever record the version.  Like this

```
git tag v1.0
```

After that, you have a couple of option for continuing development.

1) Just continue (on the current branch).  When you get to v2.0 tag it again.  If you find that you need to checkout v1.0 later use `git checkout -b v1.0-fix v1.0`

2) Continue on a new branch.  Use `git checkout -b new-dev v1.0` to create a new branch `new-dev` (and to switch to it).  As you develop, `new-dev` will be modified and the branch for v1.0 won't be touched.